# to tag NE on multiple files using Stanford NER

Tags: named-entity-recognition

I want to use Stanford NER to tag name entity in multiple files. In documentation it is said that we can use  the option `-testFiles` with list of test files separated with commas but it does not work in my case like:

```
java -cp stanford-ner.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier
     -loadClassifier ner-model.ser.gz -testFiles Test_file1.tsv,Test_file2.tsv
```

but it works when we input only one file.

Does system also have inline evaluation (FOR P, R) for all multiple files? I just wonder how it works in case of multiple files.

Thanks in advance.

Khadaka

Answer (score 1):

You have to use prop.txt file to use multiple tsv files. Check this link

https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.html#mfiles

Below is the snippet from the NER FAQ page

> How do I train one model from multiple files?
>
> Instead of setting the trainFile property or flag, set the
>   trainFileList property or flag. Use a comma separated list of files.

Comment: Better to cite relevant information from the link you posted: the link could disappear in future.